# javascript search box and edit font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, fonts

Here is a javascript for searching a certain database.  The script generates a `Search` button to submit the query, is there a way to adjust the **font/size** of the text in this button?

```
<script src="http://www.bccls.org/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://www.bccls.org/js/searchPolaris.js?v=2" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<form name="search" id="search" action="javascript:searchPolaris()">
    <input name="query" type="text" id="query" style="width: 220px">
    <input type="hidden" NAME="whichlibrary" id="whichLibrarySelected" value="119">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="newWindowCheck" id="newWindowCheck" value="newWindow">
</form>
```

Comment: on what condition you want to adjust the font size?

Answer (score 1):

You can with css:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 3rem; /* or whatever...*/
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bccls.org/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bccls.org/js/searchPolaris.js?v=2"></script>

<FORM name="search" id="search" 
action="javascript:searchPolaris()">
   <input name="query" type="text" id="query" style="width: 220px"><input type="hidden" NAME="whichlibrary" id="whichLibrarySelected" value="119">
   <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Search" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="newWindowCheck" id="newWindowCheck" value="newWindow">
</form>
```

Comment: is there a way to adjust without using CSS?

Comment: Might also add an id selector example in case he just wants to hit the instance and not the type entirely.

Comment: if you don't want to use an external stylesheet, then your option would be to use an inline style: `<input type="submit" style='font-size: 3rem;' value="Search" target="_blank">`

Comment: Inline style is still CSS ;)

Comment: <sigh> you know what i mean, Chris ;)

Comment: Hah I know, but had to bust balls. +1 either way. ;)

Comment: are there any inline style codes for adjusting Font Type?  Also, if I wanted to adjust the height of the search box as well, where would I place the   style="height: 100px"?  When I insert it before right before the style="width: 220px", it seems to remove my ability to then adjust the width.

Comment: CSS properties are available within the `style` attribute.  To add multiple css properties, just chain them separated with a semicolon: `style="font-size:3rem;height:100px;width:220px;"` etc. If you're specifying fonts, the css declaration is `font-family`.